# 3D version of seaborn.kdeplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

[Using `seaborn.kdeplot`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/distributions.html#plotting-bivariate-distributions), I can get a heatmap / kdeplot of 2 variables[image: heatmap].

How can I "raise" it to 3D, in the sense of using the height (i.e., values along the Z axis) instead of the colors to display the estimated frequency density?

I found matplotlib's `plot_surface`, but it requires the values for the points along the 2D grid in the XY plane, which kdeplot doesn't return. And is `plot_surface` the right function for this purpose anyway?

Comment: `plot_surface` is probably the right way to go but you'll have to compute the kde yourself.

Comment: @mwaskom thanks, that makes sense.